# How to remove values in list which contain alphabetical characters?

Tags: python

I am reading a `.dat` file and the first few lines are just metadata before it gets to the actual data. A shortened example of the `.dat` file is below.

> &SRS
>
> SRSRUN=266128,SRSDAT=20180202,SRSTIM=122132,
>
> fc.fcY=0.9000
>
> &END
>
> energy rc  ai2
>
> 8945.016   301.32  6.7959
>
> 8955.497   301.18  6.8382
>
> 8955.989   301.18  6.8407
>
> 8956.990   301.16  6.8469

Or as the list:

> [' &SRS\n', ' SRSRUN=266128,SRSDAT=20180202,SRSTIM=122132,\n', 'fc.fcY=0.9000\n', '\n', ' &END\n', 'energy\trc\tai2\n', '8945.016\t301.32\t6.7959\n', '8955.497\t301.18\t6.8382\n', '8955.989\t301.18\t6.8407\n', '8956.990\t301.16\t6.8469\n']

I tried this previously but it :

```
def import_absorptionscan(file_path,start,end):
    for i in range(start,end):
        lines=[]
        f=open(file_path+str(i)+'.dat', 'r')
        for line in f:
            lines.append(line)
        for line in lines:
            for c in line:
                if c.isalpha():
                    lines.remove(line)
        print lines
```

But i get this error: ValueError: list.remove(x): x not in list

i started looking through stack overflow then but most of what came up was how to strip alphabetical characters from a string, so I made this question.

This produces a list of strings, with each string making up one line in the file. I want to remove any string which contains any alphabet characters as this should remove all the metadata and leave just the data. Any help would be appreciated thank you.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your dat file?

Comment: Can you show us what you have tried, and how it doesn't work for you?

Comment: Insert an if statement inside inner for loop, to check if `lines` is `str`.

Comment: The lines will always be `str`. Remember: "1" is still a str.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have a suspicion you will want a more robust rule than "does the string contain a letter?", but you can use a regular expression to check:

```
re.search("[a-zA-Z]", line)
```

You'll probably want to take a look at the [regular expression docs](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html).

Comment: Why? Your answer matches `str.isalpha()`. Why not just use this? And also, mention WHERE it should go (of course, I'd recommend the inner `for` loop).

Comment: `str.isalpha()` requires every character in the string to be a letter, not just a single character. I imagine the OP is not familiar with the `re` module, but is familiar with `if` statements, and did not wish to do all the work for them.

Comment: Oh that's fair. As a side point, you can still call `isalpha` using the `any` statement (looping through the characters in each line). Although I might just make that my own answer instead of invading yours.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you can use the `any` statement to check for letters. Inside your inner `for` loop add:

```
If any (word.isalpha() for word in line)
```

Notice that this will say that "ver9" is all numbers, so if this is a problem, just replace it with:

```
line_is_meta = False
for word in line:
    if any (letter.isalpha() for letter in word):
    line_is_meta = True
        break
    for letter in word:
        if letter.isalpha():
            line_is_meta = True
            break
if not line_is_meta: lines.append (line)
```